# CSS - Cannot get rid of margin

Tags: html, css

My problem is that i have a header that is suppose to take up the whole top of the page but for some reason there is a margin on both sides.

My Css:

```
#top_bar{
    background-color:#000;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, this stems from the default margin/padding of body. Try adding

```
html,body {padding:0; margin:0;}
```

Comment: I don't know what you just did, but it works so Thanks So SO SO Much!

Comment: @Matthew Carter  Browsers provide a default stylesheet, that includes stuff like making headings bigger and <strong> bolder. It also includes a padding on body that prevents text from being at the very edge of the monitor. The CSS in my answer essentially removes this and lets you fill the whole space